# How to explicitly include decision variables in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, nonlinear-optimization

I’m implementing a neural network from a paper in PyTorch. Here is the screenshot of the paper: [image: Paper reference]
Here N_Psi is a neural network, and K is a decision matrix. The way I came up with is to include an extra linear layer for K, but wondering if there's any chance to explicitly define K as decision variables in a more direct way?

Any hint would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "*explicitly define `K` as decision variables in a more direct way*"?

Comment: Like the way to define decision variables in an optimization problem in cvxpy, casadi etc. If this is not possible in pytorch, wondering what is the most convenient way to include the extra decision variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your decision matrix as a fully connected layer with no bias, using [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html). Then you have to add this additional layer to your optimizer parameter list. Given `N` your neural network, `K` you linear layer, and `optim` your `torch.optim.Optimizer` class, you can:

```
optimizer = optim(list(N.parameters()) + list(K.parameters()))
```

Then in the inference stage, given `x_n+1` and `x_n`, do something like:

```
mse = F.mse_loss(N(x_n+1), K(N(x_n)))
reg_1 = K.weight.pow(2).sum()
reg_2 = p2v(N.parameters()).sum()
loss = mse + lamb_1*reg_1 + lamb_2*reg_2
```

*Where we imported:*

- `torch.nn.functional` as `F`
- `torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector` as `p2v`

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting defining a linear layer for K. That helps!